# How can I write this in a more dynamic way?

Tags: matlab

As the title says, I'm looking for making a dynamic version of this one but i can't figure out how to do this. In this case r=30 and the difference between the cases is 5 (i<=5, i<=10, 1<=15 etc) Can somebody help me ?

```
for i = 1:r
  if     i <= 5
    a_m_o(length(a_m_o)+1) = m_o(i) - m_o(1)
  elseif i <= 10
    a_m_o(length(a_m_o)+1) = m_o(i) - m_o(6)
  elseif i <= 15
    a_m_o(length(a_m_o)+1) = m_o(i) - m_o(11)
  elseif i <= 20
    a_m_o(length(a_m_o)+1) = m_o(i) - m_o(16);
  elseif i <= 25
    a_m_o(length(a_m_o)+1) = m_o(i) - m_o(21);  
  elseif i <= 30
    a_m_o(length(a_m_o)+1) = m_o(i) - m_o(26);
  end
  if a_m_o(i)<0
    a_m_o(i) = a_m_o(i) + 400;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers guide you towards avoiding code duplication. But the other thing you need to do is [vectorize your code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). Vectorizing is a way to avoid loops, which are relatively slow in MATLAB (even though they are much faster nowadays than they used to be when I started using MATLAB).

We'll start with creating an array that indexes `m_o` the way you do in your loop:

```
I = floor(((1:r)-1)/5)*5+1;
```

This creates an array `[1,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,6,11,11,...]`. You can also use `repmat` or `mod` as suggested in the other answers.

Indexing `m_o` using `I` (`m_o(I)`) is the same as writing `[m_o(1),m_o(1),m_o(1),m_o(1),m_o(1),m_o(6),m_o(6),m_o(6),...]`. That is, we're indexing the same element 5 times, creating 5 copies of that element in the output array. So now you can write:

```
a_m_o = a_m - a_m(I);
```

Your test for negative results can also be vectorized:

```
J = a_m_o < 0;
a_m_o(J) = a_m_o(J) + 400;
```

Besides that vectorized code is faster, it's often also a lot easier to read!

Note also that your code `a_m_o(length(a_m_o)+1) = ...` is very inefficient: the array `a_m_o` is resized every loop iteration. Newer MATLABs actually identify this use case and optimize around it, but it's still much faster to [pre-allocate the array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html):

```
a_m_o = zeros(size(m_o));
for i = 1:r
  a_m_o(i) = a_m(i) - a_m(1);
end
```

For `r=30` you might not notice the difference, but for larger arrays the savings can be huge.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you group the natural numbers (without zero) in groups of 5 (or `n`) elements en map each element in a group to its first element. Such an operation can typically be done using the modulus:

```
function k = map (i)
    n = 5;
    m = mod(i, n);
    if m == 0
        m = 5;
    end
    k = i - m + 1;
end
```

This will map `1, 2, 3, 4 and 5` to `1`; `6, 7, 8, 9 and 10` to `6`; ...

Answer (score 0):

```
r_help=repmat([1:5:length(r)],[5,1]); %create a helper vector which got the indices in it which you need.
r_help=r_help(:);

for i = 1:r
    a_m_o(length(a_m_o)+1) = m_o(i) - m_o(r_help(i));
    if a_m_o(i)<0
        a_m_o(i) = a_m_o(i) + 400;
    end
end
```